# How to prevent knockout.js from deleting form field values prefilled by FireFox when applying bindings

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox, knockout.js

FireFox prefills certain form values in input boxes after loading pages (such as usernames etc...).

If I apply Knockout.js bindings to a prefilled form, at the moment of applying bindings Knockout will clear out the input fields (causing short flicker).

Is there a way to keep the prefilled values rather than erasing them?

```
   var UserModel = function() {
        this.username = ko.observable();
        this.password = ko.observable();
        this.passwordRepeat = ko.observable();
        ....
   }
   ....
   domReady(function() {
      //values prefilled by FireFox in input box bound to username are 
      //erased after applyBindings is executed
      ko.applyBindings(new UserModel());
   });
```

Comment: Always a tricky issue... did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103947/applying-knockout-to-a-filled-form-without-wiping-the-forms-data-because-of-an

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, the link (for similar issue) says the only way is to fetch the values manually before binding and then applying them manually to the model (which mostly defeats the purpose of using knockout)... If there's no other way I'll probably turn off autocomplete on the forms to side step the problem. It's not ideal but avoids the flicker.

Comment: There's just no way to know, a priori, when the auto-complete will fire... you would have to tap into something like an 'afterAutoFillComplete' function which is impossible given the range of Auto-fill plugins, extensions and build-in browser capability. Seems like using the autocomplete=off attribute is the only guranteed approach.

Comment: You could try using the new textInput binding. Seems to be orchestrated around dealing with some of these things. May give you different, although still undesirable, results. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html

Comment: I am using textInput binding but it doesn't seem to help. According to posts elsewhere on the internet it seems to help with various autofills / autocompletes that happen after the bindings are applied, however it doesn't help in this particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom binding, or overwrite/extend the textInput and/or value bindings to initialize observables with values from the DOM.

```
// w/ custom binding
ko.bindingHandlers.prefilledText = {
    init: function(el, valueAccessor) {
        // set initial value
        var initVal = $(el).val()
        valueAccessor()(initVal)

        // apply normal textInput binding
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(el, {
            textInput: valueAccessor()
        })
    }
}

// w/ extended textInput binding

// save reference to initial binding
var _textInputBinding = ko.bindingHandlers.textInput

ko.bindingHandlers.textInput = {
    init: function(el, valueAccessor) {
        // set initial value, same as before
        var initVal = $(el).val()
        valueAccessor()(initVal)

        // pass on to the regular textInput binding
        _textInputBinding.init.apply(this, arguments)
    },
    // don't forget the update function either!
    update: _textInputBinding.update
}
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyWebb/64st5dct/2/)!